# PHP Get every Nth item in loop but group them by sets of 6

Tags: php, arrays, loops, iteration, slick.js

I am using Slick Slider to build a slider of events. Each "slide" consists of a group of 6 events of different sizes (shown in the picture below):

[image]

PHP:

```
<div id="eventsList">

    <div class="eventsGroup">

        <?php foreach ($events as $event) { ?>

            <? $counter++; ?>

            <?php if ($counter == 1) { ?>
                <div>
                    <div class="gridblock">
                        <div class="gridblock_inner">
                            <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($counter == 2) { ?>
                    <div class="gridblock sixty">
                        <div class="gridblock_inner no_right_margin">
                            <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($counter == 3) { ?>
                <div style="width:66.666667%;float:left;">
                    <div class="gridblock onehundred">
                        <div class="gridblock_inner">
                            <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($counter == 4) { ?>
                    <div class="gridblock fifty">
                        <div class="gridblock_inner">
                            <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($counter == 5) { ?>
                    <div class="gridblock fifty">
                        <div class="gridblock_inner">
                            <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($counter == 6) { ?>               
                <div style="width:33.333333%;float:left;">

                    <div class="gridblock onehundred twohigh">
                        <div class="gridblock_inner no_right_margin doublehigh">
                            <?php  echo $event['name']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Slick Slider JS:

```
$('#eventsList').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

This code works fine if I only have 6 items in the array of course, but I'd like to modify it to scale so I can add as many events as I want and have it follow the same pattern of grouping them in sets of 6.

I tried something like this pattern initially:

```
if (($counter % 3) == 0) {
}
```

but it doesn't make sense since it's grouped in 6. How can I accomplish this so it can scale? Thank you in advance.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zf7dj05g/7/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to check if the counter is equal to 0 to 5 modulo 6; move the `$counter++` to the end of the loop, and replace each comparison with a compare to 1 less e.g.

```
<?php if ($counter == 3) { ?>
```

becomes

```
<?php if (($counter % 6) == 2) { ?>
```

So your loop as a whole would be:

```
    <?php foreach ($events as $event) { ?>
        <div class="eventsGroup">

        <?php if (($counter % 6) == 0) { ?>
            <div>
                <div class="gridblock">
                    <div class="gridblock_inner">
                        <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (($counter % 6) == 1) { ?>
                <div class="gridblock sixty">
                    <div class="gridblock_inner no_right_margin">
                        <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (($counter % 6) == 2) { ?>
            <div style="width:66.666667%;float:left;">
                <div class="gridblock onehundred">
                    <div class="gridblock_inner">
                        <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (($counter % 6) == 3) { ?>
                <div class="gridblock fifty">
                    <div class="gridblock_inner">
                        <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (($counter % 6) == 4) { ?>
                <div class="gridblock fifty">
                    <div class="gridblock_inner">
                        <?php echo $event['name']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (($counter % 6) == 5) { ?>               
            <div style="width:33.333333%;float:left;">

                <div class="gridblock onehundred twohigh">
                    <div class="gridblock_inner no_right_margin doublehigh">
                        <?php  echo $event['name']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <? $counter++; ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, what about for the others like 4 and 5?

Comment: They would become 3 and 4 respectively i.e. 1 becomes 0, 2 becomes 1, 3 becomes 2, 4 becomes 3, 5 becomes 4 and 6 becomes 5 in the new tests.

Comment: hmm, sorry but how would that look? I appreciate you taking the time to explain thanks again

Comment: how do you determine the number after the ==?

Comment: @cpcdev See my edit. I've written out the whole loop.

Comment: thanks. Sorry, I figured it out right before you posted it, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @cpcdev your comment about the "eventsGroup" div disappeared, but basically you just need to bring the start and finish into the loop. See my edit.